# Simplenote or Evernote or something else?

Tags: notes.app, network

What is the best way to keep my notes stored in the cloud? I want to access them fast and they should be editable on every device I use. (iPhone, iMac, Windows, etc.) What do you personally use? Simplenote or Evernote or is there another contender?

Answer (score 3):

I personally prefer Simplenote because it's simpler, plain text and not that fancy. Well, it's just text snippets and notes for me.

[Google](http://www.google.de/search?hl=de&q=evernote%20simplenote&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=) gets you loads of comparisons:

- [Simplenote and Evernote – in a rather large nutshell](http://isource.com/2010/02/04/simplenote-and-evernote-in-a-rather-large-nutshell-iphone-applications/)
- [Simplenote vs Evernote](http://johnny.chadda.se/article/simplenote-vs-evernote/)
- [Evernote vs. Simplenote](http://priyankpatel.posterous.com/evernote-vs-simplenote-evernote-is-great-but)

**EDIT**

If you want to look into Simplenote check out [Notational Velocity](http://scrodlog.notational.net/interesting-facts-about-simplenote-support-in)!

Answer (score 1):

If you're already a dropbox user and are willing to limit the number of cloud services you use, store your notes in dropbox :
- [Plaintext](http://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/plaintext-dropbox-text-editing/id391254385?mt=8) is a stylish text editor for iOS devices with dropbox synchro
- [Epistle](http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/productivity/epistle_orrw.html) is the equivalent for Android

Answer (score 0):

I was an early adopter of Evernote and it is a great service, but I've been using SimpleNote + Notational Velocity for a while now and I couldn't be happier. I recommend this setup to everyone I know with a Mac + iPhone.